# Ideas for simplifying design/removing a level of indirection in method calls

Tags: c++, methods, multiple-indirection

In the following bit of code below (full version of [ideone](http://ideone.com/325jy)) , the pointers to the methods `Container::void updateFoo` and `Container::void updateBar` are registered in a map `m_updateMethod`. These methods simply call `Foo::update` and `Bar::update` respectively.

Is there a way to avoid this extra level of indirection, by storing `Foo::update` and `Bar::update`?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void update( )
    {
        std::cout << "Updating Foo ..." << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bar
{
public:
    void update( )
    {
        std::cout << "Updating Bar ..." << std::endl;
    }
};

class Container
{
public:
    typedef void (Container::*updateMethod)();
    typedef std::map<std::string , updateMethod> UpdateMethodMap;

    static const UpdateMethodMap    m_updateMethod;
    static UpdateMethodMap          initializeUpdateMethodMap();
    static updateMethod             getUpdateMethod( const std::string attributeName );

    void update( const std::string name )
    {
        updateMethod updater = getUpdateMethod( name );
        if( updater )
        {
            (this->*updater)();
        }
    }

    void updateFoo()
    {
        m_foo.update();
    }

    void updateBar()
    {
        m_bar.update();
    }

private:    
    Foo m_foo;
    Bar m_bar;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by avoiding the extra indirection? do you mean avoiding the runtime overhead of an extra method call (likely zero due to inlining) or the typing overhead of writing more methods? Is a higher runtime overhead acceptable to reduce typing?

Comment: I'd like `Foo:update()` and `Bar::update()` to be called directly, and not via `Container::updateFoo()` and `Container::updateBar()` respectively (see code post ideone). In essence, I'm trying to simplify/declutter the interface of the class `Container`. (The equivalent of `Container` in my actual code has got about 15 such "updateX" methods.)

Comment: So are you willing to sacrificy some runtime efficiency for that?

Comment: I suppose runtime efficiency matters most but it would be nice to have a cleaner interface too, if possible. I just wanted to know if there's a way of removing the indirection without incurring performance penalties.

Comment: In that case I don't have an idea. However are you really sure about runtime efficiency mattering? Your code doesn't look that optimized (`std::string` keys...)

Comment: Its part of a parser, thus the `std::string`'s. I'm transmuting them to enums and numeric types.